# Правильное использование fit_generator в keras

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь понять, как работает fit_generator в keras.

У меня есть датасет, в каждом файле - 100 изображений и 100 меток.

Я написал такой генератор:

```
def GenerateData(self):

    while True:

        complete_x1 = np.zeros((500, 50, 50, 3))
        complete_x2 = np.zeros((500, 50, 50, 3))
        complete_y1 = np.zeros((500, 3))
        complete_y2 = np.zeros((500, 2))

        done = 0

        while done < 500:

            data = np.load("{}/data_resized_{}.npy".format(self._patch, self._LastID))

            self.Log('\nLoad ALL data. ID: {} - Done: {}'.format(self._LastID, done))

            for data_x1, data_x2, data_y1, data_y2 in data:

                data_x1 = self.random_transform(data_x1)

                data_x2 = self.random_transform(data_x2)

                data_x1 = self.ImageProcessing(data_x1, 0)

                data_x2 = self.ImageProcessing(data_x2, 1)

                data_x1 = np.array(data_x1).astype('float32')
                data_x1 /= 255

                data_x2 = np.array(data_x2).astype('float32')
                data_x2 /= 255

                complete_x1[done] = data_x1
                complete_x2[done] = data_x2

                complete_y1[done] = data_y1
                complete_y2[done] = data_y2

                done += 1

            self._LastID += 1

            if self._LastID >= 1058:
                self._LastID = 0

        yield [np.array(complete_x1), np.array(complete_x2)], [np.array(complete_y1), np.array(complete_y2)]
```

Всего у меня 1058 файлов. Получается 105800 изображений с метками.

Обучение модели:

```
model.fit_generator(data.GenerateData(), samples_per_epoch=1058/500, nb_epoch=15, verbose=1, workers=1)
```

Все вроде бы хорошо, но!

В самом начале тренировки GenerateData выдает следующее:

> Load ALL data. ID: 0 - Done: 0
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 1 - Done: 100
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 2 - Done: 200
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 3 - Done: 300
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 4 - Done: 400
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 5 - Done: 0
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 6 - Done: 100
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 7 - Done: 200
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 8 - Done: 300
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 9 - Done: 400
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 10 - Done: 0

И такое происходит до файла с ID 59. Получается... Он пропускает все, что идет до 59 файла? 5900 изображений?

Он просто загружает 500 изображений, после чего проходит
yield и начинает заново, с ID файла, на котором он закончил, но при этом тренировки не проходит.

Вот что идет после 59 файла:

> Load ALL data. ID: 59 - Done: 400 1/2 [=============>................]
>   - ETA: 4s - loss: 2.8177 - dense_18_loss: 2.0145 - dense_21_loss: 0.8032 - dense_18_acc: 0.2140 - dense_21_acc: 0.5780 Load ALL data. ID: 60 - Done: 0
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 61 - Done: 100
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 62 - Done: 200
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 63 - Done: 300
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 64 - Done: 400 2/2 [===========================>..]
>   - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7260 - dense_18_loss: 1.7077 - dense_21_loss: 1.0183 - dense_18_acc: 0.2720 - dense_21_acc: 0.5890 Load ALL data. ID: 65 - Done: 0
>
> Load ALL data. ID: 66 - Done: 100

Почему такое происходит?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю выбор параметра `samples_per_epoch=1058/500` - вы считаете `batch_size = 500` удачным значением для данного параметра? И кроме того `samples_per_epoch` - должно быть целым числом

Comment: @MaxU, если честно, я ни в чем не уверен. Я впервые с fit generator'ом работаю. В оф. документации keras'а прочитал, что samples_per_epoch должен быть num_samples / batch_size.

Comment: я потому и спросил - мне пока не встречались варианты где `batch_size` превышает 64, поэтому меня слегка удивил ваш выбор...

Comment: @MaxU, просто.. Я думал, что batch_size может быть любой. Поэтому я и создаю пустой np.zeros((500, 50, 50, 3)) с 500 элементами

Comment: конечно можно указать любое значение, но это может сильно повлиять на точность модели